# Grouping in Pandas while preserving tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this (there's actually 35 columns and many more tuples, but below are the relevant columns:

```
     leg_side  leg_quantity expiration product  change_type  
0        None          None       None      ZQ     inserted  
1        None          None       None      HG     inserted  
2        None          None       None      PL     inserted  
3        None          None       None      SI     inserted  
4        None          None       None      ZQ     inserted  
5        None          None       None      PL     inserted  
6        None          None       None      ZW     inserted  
7        None          None       None      SI     inserted  
8        None          None       None      ZQ     updated  
9        None          None       None      SI     inserted  
10       None          None       None      ZC     updated
..        ...           ...        ...     ...          ...  
970      None          None       None      OZ     inserted  
971      None          None       None      OZ     deleted  
972      None          None       None      OZ     updated  
973      None          None       None      ZC     inserted  
974      None          None       None      OZ     inserted  
975      None          None       None      ZC     inserted  
976      None          None       None      OZ     inserted
```

Now what I would like to do is group by the product, but not necessarily in the SQL sense. What I would like to do is just aggregate all tuples with similar products together and do a sub aggregation by change_type, to get a df like this:

```
     leg_side  leg_quantity expiration product  change_type  
0        None          None       None      ZQ     inserted
4        None          None       None      ZQ     inserted
8        None          None       None      ZQ     updated 
1        None          None       None      HG     inserted
2        None          None       None      PL     inserted
5        None          None       None      PL     inserted
3        None          None       None      SI     inserted
7        None          None       None      SI     inserted
9        None          None       None      SI     inserted
6        None          None       None      ZW     inserted
...
973      None          None       None      ZC     inserted
975      None          None       None      ZC     inserted
10       None          None       None      ZC     updated
970      None          None       None      OZ     inserted
974      None          None       None      OZ     inserted
976      None          None       None      OZ     inserted
972      None          None       None      OZ     updated
971      None          None       None      OZ     deleted
```

the dataframe above is organized such that all tuples with the same product name are together and then all tuples within those groups with the same change type are grouped together (preferably in the inserted, updated, deleted order). If I do pandas groupby() then tuples will be eliminated. I just want to a sense of a grouping sort. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Categorical` and [set](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#sorting-and-order) custom order. Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) data with sorting:

```
df['change_type'] = df['change_type'].astype('category')
                                     .cat
                                     .set_categories(["inserted","updated","deleted"], ordered=True)

df = df.groupby('product').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('change_type'))
                          .reset_index(drop=True)
print df

   leg_side leg_quantity expiration product change_type
0      None         None       None      HG    inserted
1      None         None       None      OZ    inserted
2      None         None       None      OZ    inserted
3      None         None       None      OZ    inserted
4      None         None       None      OZ     updated
5      None         None       None      OZ     deleted
6      None         None       None      PL    inserted
7      None         None       None      PL    inserted
8      None         None       None      SI    inserted
9      None         None       None      SI    inserted
10     None         None       None      SI    inserted
11     None         None       None      ZC    inserted
12     None         None       None      ZC    inserted
13     None         None       None      ZC     updated
14     None         None       None      ZQ    inserted
15     None         None       None      ZQ    inserted
16     None         None       None      ZQ     updated
17     None         None       None      ZW    inserted
```